# Silverlight 4/5 digitally sign XML

Tags: silverlight, digital-signature, xml-signature

I have read that you can't access Windows certificate store from Silverlight (atleast in SL3 and 4). Is it possible to acees it from SL5? If not, how can I sign XML from Silverlight?

Answer (score 1):

You can access certificate store in Silverlight 5 as it allows P/Invoke.

Our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-xml.php) library lets you sign XMLs in Silverlight 3 to 5. In SL 3 and SL 4 you need to take the certificate from the file or from constant in your code or via network and in SL 5 Windows Certificate Storage is used.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to access certificate store in SL5 using Platform Invoke? Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, looks like only out of browser applications are allowed to do P/Invoke, or you have to do a registry "hack"... http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2011/04/27/silverlight-5-beta-rough-notes-trusted-apps-in-the-browser.aspx

Comment: @redman yes, this is a restriction, if you want to use Windows Certificate Store.